# How to write a trigger to check if salary is out of min or max range of salaries pl-sql Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a trigger that check if the salary is less or greater the min or max salary using pl-sql in oracle but it keeps giving me an error , it says:Error(11,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MIN_MAX_SAL
after update 
of salary on employees
for each row
DECLARE
min_sal jobs.min_salary%type;
max_sal jobs.max_salary%type;
begin
select min_salary , max_salary into min_sal , max_sal from jobs 
where job_id = :new.job_id ;
if :new.salary > max_sal  or :new.salary < min_sal then
dbms_output.put_line('Wrong');
end if;
End;
```

Please give me some help to operate this trigger , thanks ;

Comment: As APC said, this looks valid syntactically, if not functionally. Are you sure the error is from this statement - when you submit it with `/`? Or are you running several statements together and not separating them properly, confusing the compiler? Also... don't you also need to check the `salary` if the `job_id` changes too?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is okay: [I got your trigger to compile on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5507d/3) (with some help from @Ben).

But running some inserts shows the main problem with your trigger, which is the use of DBMS_OUTPUT.  DBMS_OUTPUT is The Suck! for relational integrity because:

1. It doesn't raise an exception and so doesn't actually prevent the input of shonky data
2. The message is usually not visible to the user.

If you run the DML for the fiddle you'll see that both INSERT statements succeed, even though one breaks the rule, and no message is displayed.  That is why it's much better to hurl an exception, like this:

```
if :new.salary > max_sal  or :new.salary < min_sal then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'The input salary is outside the acceptable boundaries for this job');
end if;
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle seems to have problems with `end`; this isn't the first time I've seen it struggle and throw an incorrect ORA-00900 with peocedures as well as triggers, even using the schema panel. It works, but looks odd, if the `end` [is moved to previous line](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd572). I have no idea why... I should probably find someone to report that to really...

Comment: @AlexPoole, you're using an incorrect terminator... you can specify `/` or `;` etc: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4271 and APC it compiles fine in SQL Fiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb0fc it wasn't working for the same reason as Alex's

Comment: @Ben - still took me a while to realise what was different and spot that drop-down. Thanks, that's been puzzling me for a while!

Comment: @APC is correct.  Other than for some debugging, never, ever, ever, depend on dbms_output to notify the caller. You need to raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using a query such as:

```
select count(*)
into   salary_out_of_range
from   jobs 
where  job_id = :new.job_id and
       :new.salary not between min_sal and max_sal;
```

... and checking if salary_out_of_range equals 0 or 1. If 1 then raise the message or error.

Don't forget that you need a check whenever you change the min and max salary in the jobs table.